# Is there a Soviet equivalent to foundational Cold War documents such as the Long Telegram and NSC-68?

Tags: soviet-union, cold-war

During the early days of the Cold War, the United States produced key documents like Kennan's [Long Telegram](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/coldwar/documents/pdf/6-6.pdf) and [NSC-68](https://www.trumanlibrary.org/whistlestop/study_collections/coldwar/documents/pdf/10-1.pdf) to recognize the existence of the new conflict, understand the Soviet strategy and worldview, and develop its own strategies for approaching the conflict.

Are there any equivalent post-WW2 documents on the Soviet side? Or did the Soviets view the Cold War merely as a continuation of a prewar struggle to establish and expand Communism?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most common answer ("accepted narrative") to this question would be the [Soviet Ambassador in Washington Nikolai Novikov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nikolai_Vasilevich_Novikov)'s [telegram](https://www.mtholyoke.edu/acad/intrel/novikov.htm) of September 1946.

However, given the traditional and consistent Russian/Soviet mistrust of the West, it can hardly be viewed as a "milestone" similar to [The Long Telegram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Article#The_Long_Telegram). Rather than shape and direct policy, it merely helped reinforce the *existing* position and alert Moscow to the Washington's awakening to Moscow's attitudes.

Suffice it to observe that USSR suppressed democratic opposition to communism in Eastern Europe from the get go, even before the [VE day](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Victory_in_Europe_Day).

Comment: One such early example was the [Warsaw Uprising](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warsaw_Uprising), where Stalin personally called a halt to the Red Army advance, presumably to allow the Nazis to crush the local uprising, and only advanced into the city once it was effectively over.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75778/discussion-on-answer-by-sds-is-there-a-soviet-equivalent-to-foundational-cold-wa).